# Changing colors in python game when the ball hits the wall

Tags: python

```
import pygame
import sys
import numpy as np
import random as rn

pygame.init()

BLACK = ( 0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLUE =  (0,0,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED =   (255,0,0)
YELLOW = (255,255,0)

class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self,color,loc):
        self.loc = loc
        self.color = color

    def my_draw(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.loc)

    def my_move(self,xoffset,yoffset):
        self.loc = [self.loc[0]+xoffset,self.loc[1]+yoffset] + self.loc[2:]


size = [300, 300]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("C200 CHANGE")


r = Rectangle(RED, [0, 0, 20, 20])


while True:

    pygame.time.wait(40)

    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    r.my_draw(screen)

    if r.loc[0] > 280:
        xd = -rn.randint(1,3)
    if r.loc[1] > 280:
        yd = -rn.randint(1,3)
    if r.loc[0] < 10:
        xd = rn.randint(1,3)
    if r.loc[1] < 10:
        yd = rn.randint(1,3)
    r.my_move(xd,yd)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

I would like to ask question about how to change color when it bounces and hit the `edge(left,right)` of the wall. I've tried fixing code in r = rectangle line, but it shows black and doesn't give me anything. Also I've tried adding `r = rectangle line(YELLOW[20,20,0,0])`, Then it gives me error that xd is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer your question, I'll begin with a simplified version.
So, you can see that the only time where we talk about the color of the rect is when it is drawn: `pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.loc)` 
So logically, in order to change the color of the rect, all we need to do is change `self.color`.

This is as simple as reassigning it: `self.color = (R, G, B)`, where `R`, `G` and `B` are 3 new color values. I see you have defined a few color constants, so we'll use those.

But now, we have to perform this change upon collision with an egde, but you've already done that. So we just add a Boolean flag that we'll set to `True` after a collision:

```
has_changed_direction = False
```

Then in your loop:

```
if r.loc[0] > 280:
    xd = -rn.randint(1,3)
    has_changed_direction = True
if r.loc[1] > 280:
    yd = -rn.randint(1,3)
    has_changed_direction = True
if r.loc[0] < 10:
    xd = rn.randint(1,3)
    has_changed_direction = True
if r.loc[1] < 10:
    yd = rn.randint(1,3)
    has_changed_direction = True
r.my_move(xd, yd, has_changed_direction)

has_changed_direction = False
```

Then we modify `my_move` to accommodate the new change:

```
def my_move(self, xoffset, yoffset, direction_change):
    self.loc = [self.loc[0] + xoffset,self.loc[1] + yoffset] + self.loc[2:]
    # Rect has hit the wall and needs to change color
    if direction_change:
        self.color = rn.choice(COLORS)
```

Here is the final cleaned up code, with comments that explain every modification:

---

**EDIT**
For your desired modification, here is new code:

```
import pygame
import random as rn
# Removed numpy and sys, you didn't use these modules
# so they added useless overhead

pygame.init()

BLACK = ( 0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLUE =  (0,0,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
YELLOW = (255,255,0)

class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, color, loc):
        self.loc = loc
        self.color = color

    def my_draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.loc)

    def my_move(self, xoffset, yoffset):
        # It's much clearer to just increment loc with the offsets
        self.loc[0] += xoffset
        self.loc[1] += yoffset

    def set_color(self, new_color):
        # Change rect color to new_color
        self.color = new_color


size = [300, 300]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("C200 CHANGE")

r = Rectangle(RED, [0, 0, 20, 20])

# Object that'll let us limit framerate later on
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            # No need to import sys just to call exit,
            # it's a builtin function
            exit()

    # Replaced time.wait with the function
    # you probably meant to use to limit
    # framerate (FPS), to in this case 60
    clock.tick(60)


    # Every time rect hits a side, change its color
    if r.loc[0] > 280:
        xd = -rn.randint(1, 3)
        r.set_color(RED)
    if r.loc[1] > 280:
        yd = -rn.randint(1, 3)
        r.set_color(GREEN)
    if r.loc[0] < 10:
        xd = rn.randint(1, 3)
        r.set_color(BLACK)
    if r.loc[1] < 10:
        yd = rn.randint(1, 3)
        r.set_color(YELLOW)


    r.my_move(xd, yd)

    # Reset for next loop iteration,
    # otherwise the color will be changed
    # every frame
    has_changed_direction = False

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    r.my_draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: @Jason.R OK, I've updated to code to reflect your desired modification.